# Creating Multifield Search with Apache Solr Search

Tags: search

I'm using Apache Solr Search on Pantheon and trying to figure out how I can create an "advanced" multifield search.

For example if I have a content type called Location, with "city" and "state" fields, how can I make those fields part of the search form, similar to an exposed filter in Views?

I successfully installed and setup Facets using Facets API module, but those just add clickable links. I'm looking for the user to be able to search by multiple fields.

I also tried the Apache Solr Views Integration module, but that only allows text fields as exposed filters.

If anyone has suggestions, documentation, or a tutorial on how to do this that'd be great. Obviously I could do it with Views but I do not want these searches hitting the Drupal database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Custom Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search) module. Create a search block with your custom filters (taxonomy list). And enable "Allow user input using the URL" in your Apache-solr settings page (ADVANCED SEARCH PAGE OPTIONS section).